# Laravel 5.2 relationship with pivot table

Tags: php, database, laravel

my tables:

[image: tables]

1. every part contain many of card.
2. every card  belong to many of part.

now,using laravel eloquent model how can fetch all card for a part without add more column to database

Comment: you should look https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your relationships like below:

```
class Part extends Model
{
    public function cards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cards', 'user_cards');
    }
}
```

Then you can fetch all the cards for a part like below:

```
$cards = Part::with('cards')->find($part_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Part::whereHas('cards', function($query) use ($cardId){
  $query->where('id', $cardId);  
})->get();
```

And your model relation should contain like this, for Part.php

```
public function cards(){ 
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Card');    
}
```

And for Card.php

```
public function parts(){ 
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Part');    
}
```